# How to prevent JavaScript dialogue from triggering browser controls in PWA

Tags: javascript, dialog, progressive-web-apps, webbrowser-control, web-manifest

I've recently noticed that if a PWA, bookmarked to the home screen of my Android phone triggers any JavaScript dialogue boxes, it introduces a random browser element at the top of the screen:

[Screenshot showing unexpected browser controls/title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNYu4.jpg)

The title and URL of the page is shown, but the close, settings and more icons are not functional/don't react to touch events.

I have the webmanifest display set to 'standalone', and this behaviour didn't happen until a recent update to Chrome, it seems.

I have reviewed the webmanifest documentation, but can't see any settings that could address this behaviour, which wasn't present until recently.

EDIT: This seems to have been an oddity in Chrome, and it is no longer appearing :)

Comment: what are "JavaScript dialogue boxes" - you mean like `alert`, `prompt` and `confirm`?

Comment: Yep, that would be the ones - it was an alert in this instance.

Comment: Oh, I haven't used them in a production web page in over 15 years. I would suggest don't use them in any web page, not just PWA's

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JaromandaX - noted, but this is a legacy application that is working absolutely fine, and wasn't showing the browser header at all until recently. 'Not using them' isn't really a viable solution, sadly.

Comment: *this is a legacy application that **was** working absolutely fine* - browsers change. Now, unless this is one of those  all too common *"Every second major release of Chrome contains some stupid bug, just wait for the next minor release to fix it"* bugs, then, unfortunately, you'll need to fix your code ... personally, I would anyway, because those prompt/alert/confirm methods are so 1995

Comment: Thanks... personal views on those methods well and truly noted.